# Is there still any reliability gap between digital and analog mixers

Tags: live, digital, analog

In the last 10 year I've seen most concerts switch from analog to digital mixers. In the early days there were wild stories about the unreliability of digital boards and the fear of needing a restart during a concert.

Are these concerns still needed nowadays? Are digital mixers so mature that they could be considered as reliable as analog mixers?

Answer (score 6):

As always, you get what you pay for.

I have been using the Yamaha 01V for years now, and have never had to restart it. Nor have I ever had any real trouble with it.

As long as you stick with a major brand that has a good reputation, you should be fine.

One thing to keep in mind however, a digital mixer is basically a computer. Having a solid source of clean power is absolutely critical. I recommend a power filter and a UPS in all circumstances.

Comment: *Most* decent UPS's do power filtering by their very nature (by providing power from their batteries, not direct from the source)